# IOS Локализация

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Я начал изучать разработку под ios(swift) недавно и встретился с проблемой с локализацией.  Я хочу сделать функцию выбора языка и для этого нужно обязательно прописовать все строки в storyboard программно (NSLocalizedString)?

Answer (score 1):

Нет, не обязательно. Есть другой способ встроенной локализации сторибордов. Вы выбираете сториборд, затем в File Inspector нажимаете кнопку Localize...  и у вас  появится .strings-файл со всеми доступными строками из элементов UI на этом сториборде. Затем можно менять эти строки также, как и в обычном Localizable.strings.

Однако у этого подхода есть серьёзные минусы, из-за чего стоит подумать, стоит ли это того:

- UI-контролы в этом сгенерированном .strings-файле абсолютно неидентифицируемы, то есть непонятно, какая строка куда попадёт, из-за автоматически присваиваемых id. Поменять это поведение нельзя
- Если после создания этого файла поменять сториборд (например, добавить или удалить кнопку), содержимое файла не изменится. Есть инструменты, чтобы это обойти, но сам подход негибкий и легко что-то забыть
- Обратиться к другим локализационным строкам нельзя
- Переводы будут повторяться, если текст совпадает в строках сторибордов и Localizable.strings. Если перевод поменяется, легко забыть поменять его в двух местах, особенно без человекочитаемого одинакового id

Учитывая все выше, я бы порекомендовал всегда локализовывать программно, через NSLocalizedString.

Answer (score 1):

Рекомендую вам:

1. Пользоваться файлами локализации (Это удобный и действенный способ работы с разными языками)
2. Не используйте локализацию в сторибордах и xib, если вам нужно добавить статичный текст для UILabel, то протащите outlet и назначьте там программно текст. Данный подход упростит поддержку вашего приложения в дальнейшем.

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так же рекомендую для работы с ресурсами, такими как файлы локализации или картинки использовать SwiftGen, данная библиотека будет генерировать вам автоматически классы для удобного доступа и работы с ресурсами при каждом их использовании.

Вот вам [статья](http://catqbat.com/localizing-ios-app-with-swiftgen/) про это